# Datatables datetime plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatables

I want to sort my "Date Created" column in my table in latest date order. I saw a forum that uses the datetime datatable sorting plugin but it did not work fine. Can you help me figure this out? Here are my codes.

```
<script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>

 <script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/bootstrap_latest.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/dataTables/moment.min.js') }}"></script>

 <script src="{{ asset('promed_admin/assets/js/dataTables/datetime-moment.js') }}"></script>

 $(function(){

          $.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

          $('#table-prod-contents').DataTable({
              columnDefs : [
                  { type : 'date', targets : [10] }
              ]
          });

       });
```

**My table**

```
<table id="table-prod-contents" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Packaging</th>
            <th>Lot</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <!--<th>Amount</th>-->
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    @foreach($products as $val)

       <tr class="tbl-prod-row">
         <td><input type='checkbox'<?php //echo (($user_level == $admin_text) ? "" : 'disabled=disabled'); ?> style='width:30px; height:20px;' class='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' id='radio_check_all prod-id-checkbox' value="{{ $val->id }}"></td>
         <td><input type="hidden" display="none" class="pharma" value="{{ $val->pharmaceutical }}">{{ $val->pharmaceutical }}</input></td>
         <td>{{ $val->description }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->type }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->unit }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->packaging }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->lot }}</td>
         <td style="text-align:center;">{{ $val->price }}</td>
         <td style="color:#fff; text-align:center; <?php echo (( $val->quantity <= 10 ) ? "background-color:#C00" : "background-color:#25A602" ); ?>">{{ $val->quantity }}</td>
         <!--<td style="text-align:center;">{{ $val->amount }}</td>-->
         <td>{{ $val->expiry_date_month }}</td>
         <td>{{ $val->created_at }}</td>
       </tr>

    @endforeach

    </tbody>

</table>
```

**Table Output:**
[image]

**Database table**

[image]

Comment: Hi again! Do you have any JS errors? Have you included DataTables jQuery plugin?

Comment: No error. Take a look above with the list of javascript included files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the date strings `moment.js` returns is `Date.parse()` able' you can do this :

```
columnDefs : [
    { type : 'date', targets : [13] }
],
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/t6snpgkf/

Comment: What does targets : [13] means?

Comment: Is the column number in the example jsfiddle.... In your code is 9 or 10 for order your data @Eli

Comment: I have just updated my code above.  I already change the target to 10 where my "Date Created" field is situated, still not working.

Comment: Change $('#table-prod-contents').DataTable for $('#table-prod-contents').dataTable and try

Comment: @Eli I suppose that its you want?? https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/ or what is your data that render your table, please show your data

Comment: Please take a look in my database table above. Thanks

Comment: OK, @Eli what is the problem in your table? the ordering?

Comment: I want to sort it by Date Created. I want to display in the first row the latest date inserted data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107792/discussion-between-cmedina-and-eli).

Comment: the jsfiddle link isn't working and same jsfiddle can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913328/5612015)